# How to search data in multi-dimensional array and show the result

Tags: php, arrays

I very confused now. I have the dimensional array and I want to search and also show each data. This is my array:

```
Array(
 [0] => Array(
          [unknowndata] => Array(
                            [id] => 00001
                            [content] => some text here
                           )
        )
 [1] => Array(
          [realdata] => Array(
                         [id] => 00001
                         [content] => abcdefg
                        )
        )
 [2] => Array(
          [realdata] => Array(
                          [id] => 00002
                          [content] => abcd
                        )
        )
)
```

My question is

1. how to show only the `realdata` if the key is different (in the example, the `unknowndata` is in array[0], how if the `unknowndata` is in array[n])
2. how to process the content of `realdata` (if the content is `abcd` `return true` else `return false`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
foreach($yourarray as $element){
   if(array_key_exists("realdata",$element)) {
     echo $element['realdata']['content'];
   }
}
```

Comment: so simple haha.. and how to make $element['realdata']['content'] as array again? I will accept your answer :)

Comment: What do you want to say exactly by making it an array again? :p